# Disable BizTalk receive locations and stop host instances completion time:: PowerShell script vs BizTalk Administration Console

Tags: powershell, biztalk

My PowerShell script for disabling receive location and stopping host instance both are took more time compare to doing same task from BizTalk Administrator Console. In my environment I have more than 200 receive locations and host instances. see the below task completion stats-

**BizTalk Admin Console:** Disable RLs :: around 2 minutes , Stop Host Instances :: around 5 minutes

**PowerShell Script:** Disable RLs :: 30-40 minutes , Stop Host Instances :: around 30 minutes

-----------Disable BizTalk Receive Location----------

```
$rcvLocations = get-wmiobject MSBTS_ReceiveLocation -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter {IsDisabled = "False"}

foreach($rcvLocation in $rcvLocations){ 
   [void]$rcvLocation.Disable()
}
```

------------- Stop BizTalk Host Instance------------

```
$hostInstances = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter {HostType = 1 and ServiceState = 4 and IsDisabled = "False"} 

foreach($hostinstance in $hostInstances){ 
    $hostinstance.Stop()
}
```

I will appreciate you!

If completion time of my task from PowerShell script is near to same as from Bts Admin console.

Comment: Possible the Admin console is doing some things in parallel.  Maybe you need to change your script to do that.  e.g. have a master script that launches multiple child scripts.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail on it.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, changing the Like to whatever pattern you want based on your host naming.

```
$StartTime = $(get-date)

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $hostInstances = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter {HostType = 1 and ServiceState = 4 and IsDisabled = "False" }
    foreach($hostinstance in $hostInstances){ 
        if ($hostinstance.HostName -Like "*Receiving*" -or $hostinstance.HostName -Like "*Clustered*")
        {
          $hostinstance.Stop()
        }
    }
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $hostInstances = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter {HostType = 1 and ServiceState = 4 and IsDisabled = "False" }
    foreach($hostinstance in $hostInstances){ 
        if ($hostinstance.HostName -Like "*Sending*")
        {
          $hostinstance.Stop()
        }
    }
}


Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $hostInstances = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter {HostType = 1 and ServiceState = 4 and IsDisabled = "False" }
    foreach($hostinstance in $hostInstances){ 
        if ($hostinstance.HostName -Like "*Processing*")
        {
          $hostinstance.Stop()
        }
    }
}

While (Get-Job -State "Running")
{
  Start-Sleep 10
}


$elapsedTime = $(get-date) - $StartTime

$totalTime = "{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f ([datetime]$elapsedTime.Ticks)

Write-Host "Total Time: $totalTime"
```